# Changing UIView's transform doesn't affect constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios11

In iOS 11 changing UIView's transform property (e.g. scale) doesn't affect constraints that bound to this view. In iOS 10 all works as expected.

Code I have:

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        // top view
        let topView = UIView()
        topView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
        topView.backgroundColor = .black
        view.addSubview(topView)

        topView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        // bottom view
        let bottomView = UIView()
        bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomView.backgroundColor = .black
        view.addSubview(bottomView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            bottomView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            bottomView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.leftAnchor),
            bottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8)
        ])
    }
}
```

What do I **expect** (iOS 10):

[image: expected result]

What do I **have** (iOS 11):

[image]

As you can see, `topView` scaled, but `bottomView` doesn't laid out correctly. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's `UIView / Transform` Docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform):

> **Warning**
>
> When the value of this property is anything other than the identity transform, the value in the frame property is undefined and
>   should be ignored.

So, the result you got in iOS 10 *just happened to be* what you got, rather than it being *the correct* result.

Comment: So is there a solution to this problem? Applying a transform and keeping the constraints updated?

Answer (score -1):

What is happening to the bottom view is that it's aligning to the top view's left anchor BEFORE you tell it to scale to %50 and it's adding 8 pixels. I would hard code the left constraints. Check out [This Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/174078/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial-2) for a guide on how to do that with the visual format language.