# iOS: UIView changes size when animating, how do I prevent that?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having some issues in my xcode project, with a UIView changing size when I drag it.  Please see this GIF and you'll see what I mean:

[UIView Resizing on drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOZ7Y.gif)

I'm animating it using panGestureRecognizer. I've got a whole bunch of animations set up for x and y gestures, and the problem seems to arise in the .changed method of the gesture handler (forgive my ignorance of correct terminology here, still new to this)

The animations work great, it's just the dialogView (the modal) that seems to resize when I do the .changed animation.

So here is the code I'm using to animate the dialogView when I drag it :

```
if gesture.state == .changed {
        if velocity.x > 100 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.dialogView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 50)
            }) { (completed) in
            }
        }

        if velocity.x < -50 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.dialogView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -50)
            }) { (completed) in
            }
        }
    }
```

It rotates and I was just so happy  I could get that working.

Just for context, here is the beginning of the gesture function that I put all my animations in:

```
@objc func panGestureRecognizerAction(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
    let velocity = gesture.velocity(in: view)

    view.frame.origin = translation
```

The dialogVIew is a UIView with a vertical stack view. (Screenshot attached of the modal view controller's storyboard.

[Task Detail View Controller Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAYjp.png)

Anything I'm missing here? Would appreciate any advice a lot.

Comment: Oh, just a note I'm going to do stuff on animation completion later that's why those are empty for now.

Comment: The extra space is going to the areas just above and below the "Good Morning" paragraph. We need to see all code affecting layout: Autolayout constraints and any manual manipulations. Separately, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747666/changing-uiviews-transform-doesnt-affect-constraints which mentions: "When the value of [transform] is anything other than the identity transform, the value in the `frame `property is undefined and should be ignored"

Comment: If the dialogView is inited according to the frame, all the code looks fine. However, if the dialogView is constrained by auto layout, please show the constraints in IB. That was the issue leading to an actual size during animation.

Comment: Thank you for your response @BaseZen, I will go through this link now, thanks for that. To answer your other questions, I have 4 auto layout constraints on the stackview, which have a constant of 20 from the dialog view.

the constraints for the DimView, which is the background that fades in/out, are all set to 0 from the superview. 

the dialogView is 100 from super view top and bottom and 15 from left right. I'll paste the code below this comment

Comment: Sorry, I am nw to stackexchange and can't paste all that code in this comment. Here is a paste bin, note that I did link those contraints to IB outlets but did not use it yet.
https://pastebin.com/EVCqHKfh

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It seems that setting the autolayout constraint of the top of the dialogView realtive to the Safe Area was the problem. I changed to be relative to the superview and that resolved the issue. Thank you @E.coms and @BaseZen for pointing out that auto layout must be the issue. It works perfectly now that I set that relative to View, not Safe Area. Thanks so much.